# Get Chrome to report errors where they occur, not where they are caught

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Jucm/1/ (view the console)

```
blah = function() {
    herpderp
}

try {
    blah()
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

When you catch an error like this, it doesn't show the normal error that you'd see in the console. We're using the catch here for a specific purpose, is there a way to keep this while still logging an error by default?

Comment: That's the point of error handlers, they take precedence over the default handler. Do you need this all the time, or just while debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was looking for was

```
throw(e)
```